# Recommended hot-water pipe diameter to minimize time to hot-water at the tap

Tags: plumbing, hot-water

For a new build, I'll be running pipe from the hot-water tank to the two bathrooms, which are about 40' away on the other side of the house. One aim is to avoid the situation where it's necessary to run the bathroom hot-water taps for several minutes just to get the first few drops of hot water.

I see two options:

1. run a 3/4" trunk-line from the hot-water tank across the house, and then t-off to each bathroom with 1/2" pipe.
2. run two 3/8" pipes from the hot-water tank directly to each of the two bathrooms.

The first option seems to maximize overall flow, but means having to empty out a long length of 3/4" pipe before hot water reaches the taps. The second option would help minimize the lag, but I'm concerned about anemic hot-water flow, particularly to the showers.

I wish to avoid a recirculating pump.

What's the better option?

Comment: Insulating the pipes with pipe insulation or go with a re-circulation pump system.

Comment: If its new construction, consider a second water heater near that bathroom or at least point of use heaters for the sinks so you get almost instant hot water.  If a second heater isn't an option, you can install a second pipe to support a recirculation pump.

Comment: What will the GPM flow of your shower heads be?

Comment: Shower heads are 2.5 GPM.

Comment: Edit: Added note that recirculating pump is not an option in this particular case.

Comment: Now I'm curious why you don't want a recirc pump?  I've always thought they were a good option if you can plumb in a loop for it, but have never had one.

Comment: Would go option one and insulate the pipes as much as possible, pipe insulation plus batt insulation.  Larger pipe usually loses heat slower compared to smaller pipes.  Maximizing insulation will keep water hot longer, should get a few hours useful heat retention.

Comment: Move the hot water tank closer to the point of use.

Comment: Insulation does **nothing** to help initial lag. All it will do is slow the rate at which water in the pipes becomes cold again after having the tap off briefly.

Comment: Whether or not you want to put in a recirc pump, now is the time to put in the pipe.  Maybe a control wire as well; push a button to run the recirc pump (only) when you want hot water.

Comment: I appreciate the check mark on my answer, @Michael, but make sure you've read and understood the comments added after it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see much difference in the two options you've given. Either way you've got 40' of pipe of cold to tepid water to clear out before you get hot water from the tank.

The only advantage to option 1 is if you expect both bathrooms to be in use simultaneously or nearly so - then there's one long line to be cleared by the <s>sucker</s> first user, and the other gets hot water much more quickly.

You'd do a bit better with insulation, but that still won't help for that first use in the morning, it will have lost whatever amount of heat overnight, it'll have just done it more slowly.

Your best best are either:

- Recirculation pump to ensure that the line is always full of hot water. This is somewhat inefficient as you've got a pump running regularly and you're pulling hot water from the tank, allowing it to cool to a set point, then pumping it back in to replace it with fresh hot water. Besides, you've ruled it out.
- Point of use instant hot water heaters.

  - If you run one line, then Tee it, you could have the heater just before the Tee. You'd still wait a few moments for the remaining line to empty of cold water, but it would be a far shorter wait.
  - AIUI, you can put it on the hot line and it'll only heat if the incoming water is below the cutoff temp. This way, it gives you hot water instantly, but cuts off once you've got hot water from the (gas powered, right? :D) main tank heater.

Comment: "Either way you've got 40' of pipe of cold to tepid water" but it takes longer in pipes of larger diameter, since for a given flow at the fixture, replacing the total volume of water in the pipe depends on the pipe diameter x length. But yes, either way you still have to move water over 40'.

Comment: The difference between the two options is that option 1 needs to move a gallon of water before hot water reaches the bathroom, while option 2 only needs to move a quarter-gallon.

Answer (score 4):

One solution is to run a loop from the tank to each tap and back to tank, well insulated and with a small pump controlled by flow demand - as soon as there is demand then the hot water gets pumped around so fully hot is almost instant.

Less waste and do consider temperature control if needed.

Comment: The OP excluded this in an edit to the question, but it's still a good idea.

Comment: @FreeMan yes, the OP made the edit **after** I pisted this answer, perhaps it will be one of those forever changing questions.

Comment: Yeah, the _after_ was implied in my comment. It wasn't clear, sorry about that. It's still a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

A variation on the recirc pump:

- You will need the recirc pipe, also control wires
- Pressing a button at the point of use (maybe additional buttons elsewhere?) triggers a timer, which runs the recirc pump for a few minutes

Hot water, no wasted water and don't have the same level of heat loss from the pipes when not in use.